# Radical of a module and semi-simplicity

Tags: modules, algebras

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional $A$-module for $A$ an algebra. If $\text{rad}(M)$ is taken to be the intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$, then I would like to prove $M/\text{rad}(M)$ is semi-simple.

Can you please provide a **hint** rather than a full solution for how to approach this? Thank you.

Comment: It seems two arguments are $\text{rad}(M/\text{rad}(M)) = \{0\}$, and if $\text{rad}(M) = \{0\}$ and $N$ is a maximal submodule then $M = N \oplus S$ where $S=M/N$ is simple